# Understanding Partial Likelihood Deviance vs lambda relationship in LASSO

Tags: machine-learning, lasso, regularization, ridge-regression, glmnet

I'm analyzing gene expression data using regularized linear regression models (`lasso`-`elastic net`-`ridge`) and would like to interpret the relationship between genes (predictor variable, scaled) and various clinical parameters (response variables). These response variables include survival outcome and clinical classifiers (tumor type etc). I checked out the `glmnet` [vignette](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/Papers/Glmnet_Vignette.pdf) and Tibshirani/Hastie's Introduction to Statistical Learning books and lectures. My question has to do with interpreting the relationship between lambda and the deviance.

In the `glmnet` vignette, I saw `cv.glmnet()` survival cross-validation output produces the following plot:

[image]

***My data shows an inverse trend though:***

[image]

I'm trying to understand why this is the case. I would have expected that, with the increasing `lambda` (ie. increased penalization of coefficients), the deviance should increase (ie. less biased fit), similar to what is seen in the `glmnet` vignette. Why is my data showing this trend? Also, what do the numerical values of `lambda` and `Partial Likelihood Deviance` tell me about the linear regression model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's two very different datasets, if you run the example in the vignette:

```
data(CoxExample)
dim(y)
[1] 1000    2
dim(x)
[1] 1000   30
```

There's only 30 genes in the example and looking at the numbers on top of your plot, you have > 100, so the range of lambda tested goes lower.

The range of lambda goes all the way to 10^-8 whereas in the first plot its 10^-5. The range of the likelihood deviance is much larger too in the first plot.

You can check out this [publication](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4824408/) where the authors apply glmnet cox on a dataset similar to yours. They performed CV and have a plot similar to yours, and then zoomed in on the lower deviance part.

[image]

I guess it makes sense for this kind of data because a lot of the genes are correlated and if you go with no penalization, fitting all of them gives a high deviance. Another thing to take note of in your plot and theirs is the number on top which reflects the non-zero coefficients. It's actually around the same (~30) which suggest having about 30 genes provides a reasonable prediction.

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome 